# Setting variable in another class in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a map-controller where the user can tab the map to add a new marker. The idea is then to store the coordinates in the new marker-class. The problem I am facing is setting those variables.

**NewMarkerController.h**

```
@interface NewMarkerController : UIViewController
{
    NSNumber *posLat;
    NSNumber *posLng;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *posLat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *posLng;

@end
```

I am also synthesizing this in the .m file is that makes any difference.

**MapController.m**

```
NewMarkerController *vc = [[NewMarkerController alloc] init];
[vc posLat:coordinate.latitude];
```

The last line shows an error saying `No visible @interface for 'NewMarkerController' declears the selector 'postLat'`, but...there is...?

Can anyone spot the problem I am having here?

Comment: `vc.posLat = coordinate.latitude;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax:

```
[vc posLat:coordinate.latitude]
```

means that posLat is a function of the vc kind of class. As you want to set a variable, if you synthesized it you can just do:

```
[vc setPosLat:coordinate.latitude]
```

or

```
vc.posLat = coordinate.latitude
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[vc setPosLat:coordinate.latitude];
```

or

```
vc.posLat = coordinate.latitude;
```

Comment: God damnit, i tried with `SetPosLat`, but I see now that it should be lowercased. Thanks! PS: Can't accept for another 11 min, so I'll do it asaic